# tensorflow.contrib.learn.DNNclassifier missing 1 required positional argument: 'feature_columns'

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm using jupyter notebook to write a deep neural network code. I've encountered this problem when trying to create a DNNClassifier.

```
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as learn
classifier = learn.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10, 20, 10], n_classes=2)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-0273d6847e2b> in <module>()
----> 1 classifier = learn.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10, 20, 10], n_classes=2)

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'feature_columns'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass correct arguments [`tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNClassifier), here you didn't pass`feature_columns` argument.

For example, you can use `real_valued_column` as features_columns

```
feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=1)]
classifier = learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns, hidden_units=[10, 20, 10], n_classes=2)
```

Comment: What does that do exactly? What are the data that are being passed to the DNNclassifier in this case?